# How to create multiple button on and off common codebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to create multiple buttons using `storyboard`. Here, each buttons having on and off `background` and `title` color change. In this process as of now I am doing same logic repeated in each button action. Now, instead of that I have to create a common function within one time logics for all `button` action have to call and work like a on and off individually.

How to make this below logic in a common `function` and call it from multiple button actions.

**Code Base**

```
  @IBAction func firstbuttonClick(_ sender: Any) { 
        if button_isActive {
            self.tasktypeButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1843137255, green: 0.6823529412, blue: 0.9764705882, alpha: 1)
            self.tasktypeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        } else {
            self.tasktypeButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.80803, green: 0.803803, blue: 0.805803, alpha: 1)
            self.tasktypeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: .normal)
        }
        button_isActive = !button_isActive
    }
```

Comment: Connect all the button actions to the same `@IBAction firstbuttonClick`.

Comment: @PGDev is it a good practice? Also, one more thing I need to detect each button click action because next process I am going to store some values (That is button name).

Comment: That's what you do when you need to execute the same code at each button's action. Also, I didn't understand another requirement.

Comment: @PGDev  next I need to detect which button is user clicked and based on that I need to store some value. So If I maintain all button in a single action, How to detect which button is clicked by user?

Comment: I've added the answer. See if you can get that working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create only one `function` as below and connect all the button actions in `storyboard` to this `function` so that any `button` will update its state.

```
@IBAction private func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if button_isActive {
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1843137255, green: 0.6823529412, blue: 0.9764705882, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    } else {
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.80803, green: 0.803803, blue: 0.805803, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: .normal)
    }
    button_isActive = !button_isActive

    // To differentiate different buttons
    switch (sender.tag) {
    case 0:
       print(sender.title(for: .normal))
    case 1:
       print(sender.title(for: .normal))
    default:
       print(sender.title(for: .normal))
    }
}
```

You can also set `tag` for each in the `storyboard` and differentiate in above method to know what `button` click is this.

Comment: Kindly don't use others comments as answers.

Comment: @PGDev Can you please verify if your comment was added earlier than my half written answer?

Comment: You can definitely see the timings at which the comment was posted.

Comment: @Kamran Thank you btw how can I set tag into storyboard?

Comment: @DebSaga Yes, you can set a different `tag` for each `button` in `storyboard`.

Comment: @Kamran Now I didn't get proper on off mean selection check and uncheck not working properly. every time I am doing double touch. is there anything I did mistakes? The `button_isActive` default `true` I declare in global.

Comment: @DebSaga In that case you have to change `button_isActive` to `sender.isSelected`

Comment: @Kamran I am having mon, tue, wed, etc buttons. here, user need to check and unselect each button separately also they need to select same time multiple selection. now the changes happening after double click in a each buttons.

Comment: @Kamran but if use 'sender.isSelected' I can't able to disable button default selection background color.

Comment: @DebSaga The answer is based on the information provided in the question and if the same code was working repetitively inside each button action then it will work same with above single method. I can't of be of much help without understanding the exact issue. May be you can edit your question or ask another question specific to that problem.

Comment: @Kamran I disabled button type system to custom so now default selection color disabled. last one I am getting warning `Conditional cast from 'UIButton' to 'UIButton' always succeeds` from your code line at `if let button = sender as? UIButton`. how to remove the warning?

Comment: @DebSaga In my code, there is no line as `let button = sender as? UIButton`. If you including it from somewhere else then the fix is `let button = sender`

Comment: @Kamran I am using `sender.isSelected` `if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            if button.isSelected { } else{}`. Instead of button_isActive. here I am getting that warning

Comment: Just remove outer most `if-condition` (i.e, `if let button = sender as? UIButton {`). And use `if sender.isSelected { } else {}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func btnactn(btnTag:Int)
{
    print(btnTag)
    switch btnTag {
    case 0:
          self.btn1.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1843137255, green: 0.6823529412, blue: 0.9764705882, alpha: 1)
          self.btn1.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    case 1:
        self.btn2.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.80803, green: 0.803803, blue: 0.805803, alpha: 1)
        self.btn2.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)

    default:
        break
    }
}



@IBAction func btnActn1(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    self.btnactn(btnTag: sender.tag)
}

@IBAction func btnActn2(_ sender: UIButton)
{
      self.btnactn(btnTag: sender.tag)
}}
```

its working i have tried this. you just need to connect button outlets and its functions.you can try this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Btw my question is different. Please read my question once again. I am looking on-off logic in a common function and each and every button need to call and each button individually need to work on-off. Because multiple button user can do multiple enable and disable.

Comment: If I have more buttons, then instead of writing different action you can write 1 action for all of your button.

Comment: @DebSaga, you can try my answer which fulfills your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect all `UIButton` action in one like below code.

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    else {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    //For identifing which button is tapped
    if sender.tag == 1 {
        // Do your task
    }
    else if sender.tag == 2 {
        // Do your task
    }
}
```

If you want to detect which button is tapped, you can set tag to `UIButton` from `UIStoryBoard`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all connect all the `UIButtons` in the `storyboard` to the same `@IBAction`. Also, don't forget to select the `UIButton` as parameter type when creating the `@IBAction`.

Next, in the method `sender` is the `UIButton` that is clicked. So you can use that for further configuration.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.backgroundColor = sender.isSelected ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.1843137255, green: 0.6823529412, blue: 0.9764705882, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0.80803, green: 0.803803, blue: 0.805803, alpha: 1)
    sender.setTitleColor(sender.isSelected ? .white : .darkGray, for: .normal)

    //User sender to get the button that is clicked...
    let title = sender.titleLabel?.text
    print(title)

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

One more thing, use `isSelected` to manage the `backgroundColor` and `titleColor` of the button instead of a separate `button_isActive` property.